# Why does code continue after calling TImage.Picture.LoadFromFile?

Tags: image, delphi, performance-testing

I'm doing some comparisons between the performance of the standard VCL `TImage` control and various other third-party alternatives. I'm using `GetTickCount` to measure how long it takes for the image to load. In reality it takes about 4 seconds, however `LoadFromFile()` returns almost immediately to my surprise!

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FStart:= GetTickCount;
  imgStandard.Picture.LoadFromFile(txtFilename.Text);
  FEnd:= GetTickCount; //<-- Put a breakpoint here to observe immediate return in debug
  lblStandard.Caption:= IntToStr(FEnd-FStart)+' Msec';
end;
```

Loading the same JPEG file in both the image controls visually takes just as long as, for example, comparing with the `TImage32` from Graphics32. Both block the UI during this time as expected, at about 4 seconds. The GR32 reports, for example, 3734 Msec, while the standard one only reports 16 Msec.

Why does this happen? How can I accurately measure the time it takes for the image to really load into a `TImage`?

Comment: For the standard control, is the image decoding happening during painting. Whereas for GR32 it is decoded during the load phase. You can check this by breaking into the program after a couple of seconds, switching to the main thread, and inspecting the call stack.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I stepped through the VCL code and as far as I can tell, from the code I can see, it should be blocking the main thread. I don't see anywhere that it spawns off any additional thread for rendering, unless I'm missing it.

Comment: I don't think there is necessarily any other thread. Just that the compressed data is only decompressed on demand, when the control needs to be painted. You should do the debugging exercise that I suggested. That would let you find out what is happening and remove any doubt. Why guess when you can know.

Comment: As an alternative you could try and load the jpeg and then convert it to bitmap or paint it to a hidden canvas to measure the difference.

Comment: @R.Hoek That's ultimately what I wound up doing, using `TBitmap` and `TBitmap32` for loading. Test results conclude that the standard VCL `TImage` control is actually faster than the Graphics 32 version of it. Even despite the fact that I need to load it into a `TJpegImage` first and then assign it over to a `TBitmap`, but it's still snappy.

Comment: @R.Hoek what does GDI+ have to do with this question?

Comment: @Jerry Did you investigate the way I outlined?

Comment: @R.Hoek GDI has support for 32 bit ARGB bitmaps. The processing time here is all in software decoding of jpeg images, and in fact both standard VCL `TImage` and the graphics32 code path both use the same Delphi jpeg unit from the RTL. So none of your comments was really pertinent to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

The difference between the two controls is to do with how the decompression is handled.

- When you use the VCL image control in this way, the compressed data is read from the file, but the actual decompression only happens on demand, when the control is painted.
- When you use the graphics32 image control, the decompression happens when you load the file.

Almost all of the time taken for your image is for the decompression step, which explains the the discrepancy in your timings.

> How can I accurately measure the time it takes for the image to really load into a `TImage`?

You could insert a call to `imgStandard.Update` immediately following the call to `LoadFromFile`, which would force a paint cycle, and hence force the decompression step.